# Setting up a Discrete Distribution in C++

Tags: c++, random, distribution

After hours of struggling with this issue, I cannot find any explanations for my error.

I want the computer to pick a random number (weighted) between 0 and 120 (inclusive). I have an array, interval[], which holds the numbers from 0 to 120 (inclusive). I have another array, weights[], which holds the probabilities for choosing the ith element in the array. I want to define a probability distribution function for these data.

Here is what I tried. I get an error saying that no instance of constructor matches the argument list.

Snippet of my code:

```
std::vector< int> weights(121);
for (int i = 0; i < 121; i++)
{
    weights[i] = (teamData[i]).S();
}
discrete_distribution<> dist(weights.begin(), weights.end());
```

Comment: My compiler does not know `piecewise_constant_distribution`. Are you using a library you are not telling us about?

Comment: I found it here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/piecewise_constant_distribution

Comment: I added a snippet of my code

Comment: Are you compiling with a C++11 compiler that supports `piecewise_constant_distribution` ? And compiling with C++11 support enabled? As missing either of those will cause your code to fail to compile.

Comment: I am assuming that my compiler supports piecewise_constant_distribution since it is not shown underlined in red. Also, I have C++11 support enabled.

Comment: This kind of massive revision to a single question is discouraged. Th emost you should do is add your findings/changes as notes / addendums at the bottom of the question. But in this case a _new_ question is probbably warranted. Anyway with your current changes it all seems to compile - http://ideone.com/JNL9Hu for proof. You need to give us more information to get anything else.

Comment: I wonder why it won't compile on my computer. This is the error I get:  1 IntelliSense: no instance of constructor "std::discrete_distribution<_Ty>::discrete_distribution [with _Ty=int]" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int>>>, std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int>>>)

Comment: @MichaelAnderson Do you think it's possible that my version of VS has a bug in it? I only downloaded it about a month ago.

Comment: Add the complete error message you get when compiling the example in my ideone link into your question. Then you might get an answer - I dont use VS so can't answer that.

Answer (score 4):

From your [linked page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/piecewise_constant_distribution) (emphasis mine)

> `std::piecewise_constant_distribution` produces random **floating-point
>   numbers**, which are uniformly distributed within each of the several
>   subintervals *[b<sub>i</sub>, b<sub>i+1</sub>)*, each with its own weight *w<sub>i</sub>*. The set of
>   interval boundaries and the set of weights are the parameters of this
>   distribution.

It expects floating point weights and boundaries, and one less weight than boundaries. It will also *not* output integers between 0-120, but floats.

You're passing it integer weights and boundaries so it fails to compile. But even when you fix that you're still going to get floating point values out of it...

Instead as you've discovered you want the [`disrete_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/piecewise_constant_distribution) which you can set up like this: (modified from the linked pages documentation)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    // Setup the random bits
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());

    // Setup the weights (in this case linearly weighted)
    std::vector<int> weights;
    for(int i=0; i<120; ++i) {
        weights.push_back(i);
    }

    // Create the distribution with those weights
    std::discrete_distribution<> d(weights.begin(), weights.end());

    // use the distribution and print the results.
    std::map<int, int> m;
    for(int n=0; n<10000; ++n) {
        ++m[d(gen)/10];
    }
    for(auto p : m) {
        std::cout << p.first*10 << " - "<<p.first*10+9 << " generated " << p.second << " times\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought the floating point numbers referred to the probabilities. Are you suggesting I try another pdf?

Comment: I am trying discrete_distribution instead, but I am having trouble initializing it.

Comment: Michael Anderson - I updated my question based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of code and see if you get the same problem.

```
 // piecewise_constant_distribution
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <random>

int main()
{
  const int nrolls = 10000; // number of experiments
  const int nstars = 100;   // maximum number of stars to distribute

  std::default_random_engine generator;
  std::array<double,6> intervals {0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 10.0};
  std::array<double,5> weights {2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0};
  std::piecewise_constant_distribution<double>
    distribution (intervals.begin(),intervals.end(),weights.begin());

  int p[10]={};

  for (int i=0; i<nrolls; ++i) {
    int number = distribution(generator);
    ++p[number];
  }

  std::cout << "a piecewise_constant_distribution:" << std::endl;
  for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
    std::cout << i << "-" << i+1 << ": ";
    std::cout << std::string(p[i]*nstars/nrolls,'*') << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The program runs, but I am getting an IntelliSense error that braces cannot be omitted for this subobject initializer. This error comes from the intervals and weights initialization, and not from the piecewise distribution. I also had to include <string> to get it to run.