# Using C++ discrete distribution with weights taken from a data structure

Tags: c++, probability-density

I am trying to use [discrete distribution](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/discrete_distribution/) ([here too](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution). However as you see in the examples you do this by writing:

```
std::discrete_distribution<int> distribution {2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2};
```

or

```
 std::discrete_distribution<> d({40, 10, 10, 40});
```

which is fine if you have 10 or four elements with weights. (also I don't know if the parenthesis are necessary)

But I want to use this for 1000 elements.
I have these elements in a vector of structs such as:

```
struct Particle{
   double weight;
};

std::vector<Particle> particles;
```

as you can see each element of this vector has a weight. I want to use that weight to initialize the discrete distribution.

I could go writing one by one in a very long sentence, but I don't think that is the way.
How can I put the weights of the vector in the declaration of the discrete distribution?

Comment: Hi! Take a look at the answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31153610/setting-up-a-discrete-distribution-in-c

Comment: If you have any container with weights, e.g. `vector<double> weights;` you can just do `std::discrete_distribution<> distr(weights.begin(), weights.end());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may put your all weights into `std::vector<double> weights;`, then you can initialize your discrete distribution as `std::discrete_distribution<> distr(weights.begin(), weights.end());`. Code:

```
std::vector<double> weights;
for (auto const & p: particles)
    weights.push_back(p.weight);
std::discrete_distribution<> distr(weights.begin(), weights.end());
```

Full working example code:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVBRboMwDP3nFFYnTaB21dbtCzLOsBugkGTUKk1Q4nTSEGdngdCCNH84zrPfe5ZF172IlutmHJ9Qi9ZLBcxyLc21TFbkpgQZu0XQOLKKh6kENcGVo04z6BMIETpeEHxxSyhataBTSOPrAPwobM4En/BazK2hWHgyz6MVu5NL6JbKpX3/NhygP03pfUofw5D9p0aTcnFxceDbWEi5JwPCaEfwDF2@SmePDRfSsfPuXNVcXNLuGLGtk0QnrCJVhYIs1p7QaObwV1VUwgymd6VaNdNtDg9ppWWabdXivSupbigUWLnZOEoCzrcKD4NTePd7XDeeJYTxBIwt1lZm02cHuyIZknH8Aw)

```
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    struct Particle {
        double weight = 0;
    };
    std::vector<Particle> particles({{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}});
    std::vector<double> weights;
    for (auto const & p: particles)
        weights.push_back(p.weight);
    std::discrete_distribution<size_t> distr(weights.begin(), weights.end());
    std::random_device rd;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        std::cout << distr(rd) << " ";
}
```

Output:

```
1 3 3 3 2 0 2 1 3 2 3 2 2 1 1 3 1 0 3 1
```